# CSV DictWriter not moving to next row and deleting previous values

Tags: python, csv

I have this code:

```
os.truncate('cookies.csv', 0)
fieldnames = ['domain', 'expiry', 'httpOnly', 'name', 'path', 'secure', 'value']


def open_csv(value):
    with open('cookies.csv', 'r+') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(value)

cookie = driver.get_cookie('example cookie')  # get cookie from selenium chrome webdriver
driver.close()
open_csv(cookie)
```

It should write in this format, values aren't accurate just example:

```
'domain': google.com, 'expiry': 123456, 'httpOnly': true, 'name': cookie1, 'path':/, 'secure': true, 'value': 123abc
'domain': google.com, 'expiry': 123457, 'httpOnly': true, 'name': cookie2, 'path':/, 'secure': true, 'value': 456def
```

However, it only writes in the first row, so after writing `cookie1` it will then write `cookie2` in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file for appending, using the `a+` file mode. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/1370986) for detailed explanation.